# Alternatives to List<object> in j2me?

Tags: java-me

How can I create a collection in java me?

I need something like `List<Customer> customerList=new List<Customer>` , but List do not exist in java me (at least not in this way)

I tried using Hashtables that supposedly can contain Objects , but when I retrieve a value, the return value is null:

```
c = (Customer) htCustomer.get(key)
```

I could use  `customerList[] = Customer[20]`, but arrays need a size and how am I supposed to know the number of items right from the start??

So the question is , what can I use if I need a list of custom objects in java me?? Something that can grow to accommodate new items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google "java collections"

Comment: `new List<Customer>()` wouldn't work, because `List<T>` is an interface. You can try `new ArrayList<Customer>()` or `new LinkedList<Customer>()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can get is [`java.util.Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Vector.html):

```
Vector customerList = new Vector();
customerList.addElement(new Customer(...));
Customer c = (Customer)customerList.elementAt(0);
```

Comment: yes there are no lists but vector is good enough for collections in J2ME